# Angular 2 and AEM Integration Issue

Tags: aem, angular2-template

I am trying to integrate Angular 2 with AEM. I am willing to bootstrap Angular 2 at page level so that I can wrap AEM page parsys inside Angular 2 root component. Any AEM component dragged inside page parsys would be a part of Angular 2 root component scope then. Any ideas how to achieve the same. I tried to include AEM page parsys inside typescript template section but it throws compile time error. Any help on this will be deeply appreciated

Comment: Have you tried putting `ng-app` on an upper level of where you're putting your `parsys`?